# How to uninstall iOS QuickBlox SDK from OS X project?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, quickblox

I was curious about whether the QuickBlox iOS SDK would work in a Mac OS X project.  I followed these instructions:

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework

More specifically, since my project is in Swift, I followed the ones at the bottom, the "Additional steps for Swift using Manual Installation", except that MobileCoreServices didn't exist for OS X.

When that didn't work, I messed around with the steps further up in "Manual installation" such as changing the linker flags.

It didn't work (at least not without warnings).  So I undid everything I messed with (and I'm pretty sure I only messed with things that were in the instructions).

Now, when I hit run, the project says "Build Succeeded" and the bar at the top says "Finished running", but no application opens.

I checked each of the frameworks I added and they're all gone.  I checked each of the "Build Settings" I changed and they're all back to how they were.  In Source Control when I hit "Commit" I can see that there aren't any changes to commit.  My project seems to be exactly how it used to be, and I'm left scratching my head about what could have changed.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not sure what caused this, but here's how I got my app to run again:

First, I tried adding Quickblox to a new dummy project to try to recreate the error, but the dummy project wouldn't break in the same way that my good project did.

So then I tried to use Source Control to restore my last working version by clicking "Discard All Changes...".  Source Control did not restore my last working version but instead reinstalled Quickblox, moved random files into the trash, and broke the links on all of the other files so that my list of files was mostly red.

So I decided to create a new Xcode project and move the files from my old project into this new project.  While this new project was still blank, I could test "run" and see that the blank application would open onto my computer.  So then I began the process of moving things over which took some time.

A couple of things to note when you're doing such a migration: entitlements and info.plist files, when dragged into a project, are added to "Copy Bundle Resources" and need to be deleted from that list.  Moving an xcdatamodeld file from Finder into a project doesn't work very well, but moving it straight from another project into a project does.  I had to reconfigure provisioning profiles.  Then, Core Data entities can cause errors if their "Module" is still set to the old project's name (changing these modules to "Current Product Module" worked).  After all of that, my project was up and running again!